# Anaconda 4.7.5 - Warning about conda-build <3.18.3 and issues with python packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I run the Anaconda python distribution on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS x64 and just updated the distribution with the usual `conda update --all`. After that, the command line message suggested updating the conda base defaults. Now for some reason, I am having a couple of issues. First, I am unable to launch `jupyter lab`, even after trying to reinstall `conda install jupyter`. And second I am getting this new warning message.

```
    WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632):
 Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2
 file format because you have conda-build installed,
 and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to
 get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
```

So I looked and found this [blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-we-made-conda-faster-4-7/) from today
about making Anaconda faster. But the post seems to be more information and does not seem to recommend upgrading right away.

Here is the output from `conda info`.

```
     active environment : XXX
    active env location : XXX
            shell level : 2
       user config file : ../.condarc
 populated config files : ../.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.6.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : ../anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : ../.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : ../.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.6 Linux/4.15.0-50-generic ubuntu/18.04.2 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Should I delete my old anaconda distribution and download and install the new version of 4.7, or is there a simpler fix?

**UPDATE**

So I did post this issue to the `conda` repo on Github. The current issue open against this problem is listed below. According to `msarahan` here is the basis of the problem and just a temporary workaround

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842

> 1. anaconda is a meta-package. Each version consists of a set of versions
>      that have all gone through QA together as a set. If you change any
>      version of any package in that collection, you no longer have that
>      metapackage, because you have strayed from that known set. There is a
>      special version of that metapackage, custom, that is meant to handle
>      this relaxation of constraints. The "custom" version depends only on a
>      particular version of python - it removes the constraints on all other
>      packages.
> 2. conda 4.7 builds up its candidates for addition differently
>      from earlier conda versions. It starts with specs from the history,
>      and tries to constrain things where it can, to speed up the solution.
>      When conda finds the anaconda metapackage with the "custom" version,
>      it keeps it, but all of those other dependencies are now orphaned.
>      This is why conda is removing them - they have no spec in the history
>      that tells conda to keep them.
>
> You can restore these by running `conda
>   install --only-deps anaconda`. From then on, all of those packages are
>   considered part of your explicit history, and you won't have further
>   problems like this.

Comment: FWIW I fried my mian working environment earlier today this way & spent the rest of the day trying to repair it -- so far unsuccessfully

Comment: @Daniel man sorry to hear that. Yeah I almost tried to reinstall all of anaconda but then went into the environment folder and killed some problem `site-packages`, which fixed some stuff. But I am still getting these warnings. Why do they release this stuff without clear explanations or migration paths.

Comment: My problem wasa little more complcated. With 4.6 I use `pip_interop_enabled: true
channel_priority: strict` to keep my environment sane. With these settings 4.7 starts to want to delete essential packages and without them it gets hopelessly confused. I ended up reinstalling from scratch and pinning 4.6.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
conda activate base  # or just conda deactivate
conda update conda-build
```

(Or simply `conda update -n base -c defaults conda-build`)

If this doesn't fix, try rolling back to before your update to `4.7.5`, as @LeninGF suggests, then removing conda metadata, cleaning up conda, then try the update again i.e.

```
conda list --revisions  # find number, x, before the update
conda install --revision x
rm -rf ~/.conda
conda clean --all
conda update conda
```

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the same problem by updating. The following helped me to recover base environment. I am testing in another environment to see if it works.

```
conda list --revisions
conda install --revision  dd
```

*Where **dd** is the number of the revision you wish to go back to*

For instance:

```
conda install --revision 8
```

This helped me to recover my base conda environment. Unfortunately for the tensorflow environment I had created, I had to re-install. It is also advisable to create a yaml file of your environment once you get it working so you can reinstall anytime. This is done with

```
conda env export > name.yaml
```

You need to activate your anaconda environment for that to work and point to a location in your disk where you want to store the file.

For creating the environment from the yaml file just use:

```
conda env create -f name.yaml
```

In order to make it easy I attach here the result I get for my tensorflow-gpu environment (you can see I have up to 11 revisions). Not an expert on conda but it seems that *revisions work as git*, recording your changes and letting you go back to them. However It seems also that it depends on weather you have the back up files of installations in conda environment which probably get lost when you run conda clean command:

```
(base) leninml@Lenin:~$ conda activate tf_gpu_10
(tf_gpu_10) leninml@Lenin:~$ conda list --revisions
2019-06-26 12:50:10  (rev 0)

2019-06-26 12:59:19  (rev 1)
    +_tflow_select-2.1.0 (anaconda)
    +absl-py-0.7.1 (anaconda)
    +astor-0.7.1 (anaconda)
    +blas-1.0 (anaconda)
    +c-ares-1.15.0 (anaconda)
    +ca-certificates-2019.5.15 (anaconda)
    +certifi-2019.6.16 (anaconda)
    +cudatoolkit-10.0.130 (anaconda)
    +cudnn-7.6.0 (anaconda)
    +cupti-10.0.130 (anaconda)
    +gast-0.2.2 (anaconda)
    +grpcio-1.16.1 (anaconda)
    +h5py-2.9.0 (anaconda)
    +hdf5-1.10.4 (anaconda)
    +intel-openmp-2019.4 (anaconda)
    +keras-applications-1.0.8 (anaconda)
    +keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 (anaconda)
    +libedit-3.1.20181209 (anaconda)
    +libffi-3.2.1 (anaconda)
    +libgcc-ng-9.1.0 (anaconda)
    +libgfortran-ng-7.3.0 (anaconda)
    +libprotobuf-3.8.0 (anaconda)
    +libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0 (anaconda)
    +markdown-3.1.1 (anaconda)
    +mkl-2019.4 (anaconda)
    +mkl_fft-1.0.12 (anaconda)
    +mkl_random-1.0.2 (anaconda)
    +mock-3.0.5 (anaconda)
    +ncurses-6.1 (anaconda)
    +numpy-1.16.4 (anaconda)
    +numpy-base-1.16.4 (anaconda)
    +openssl-1.1.1 (anaconda)
    +pip-19.1.1 (anaconda)
    +protobuf-3.8.0 (anaconda)
    +python-3.7.3 (anaconda)
    +readline-7.0 (anaconda)
    +scipy-1.2.1 (anaconda)
    +setuptools-41.0.1 (anaconda)
    +six-1.12.0 (anaconda)
    +sqlite-3.28.0 (anaconda)
    +tensorboard-1.13.1 (anaconda)
    +tensorflow-1.13.1 (anaconda)
    +tensorflow-base-1.13.1 (anaconda)
    +tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0 (anaconda)
    +tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1 (anaconda)
    +termcolor-1.1.0 (anaconda)
    +tk-8.6.8 (anaconda)
    +werkzeug-0.15.4 (anaconda)
    +wheel-0.33.4 (anaconda)
    +xz-5.2.4 (anaconda)
    +zlib-1.2.11 (anaconda)

2019-06-26 13:00:52  (rev 2)
    +backcall-0.1.0 (anaconda)
    +decorator-4.4.0 (anaconda)
    +ipython-7.5.0 (anaconda)
    +ipython_genutils-0.2.0 (anaconda)
    +jedi-0.13.3 (anaconda)
    +parso-0.4.0 (anaconda)
    +pexpect-4.7.0 (anaconda)
    +pickleshare-0.7.5 (anaconda)
    +prompt_toolkit-2.0.9 (anaconda)
    +ptyprocess-0.6.0 (anaconda)
    +pygments-2.4.2 (anaconda)
    +traitlets-4.3.2 (anaconda)
    +wcwidth-0.1.7 (anaconda)

2019-06-26 13:05:42  (rev 3)
     blas  {1.0 (anaconda) -> 2.7 (conda-forge)}
     ca-certificates  {2019.5.15 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     grpcio  {1.16.1 (anaconda) -> 1.16.1}
     mkl_fft  {1.0.12 (anaconda) -> 1.0.13 (conda-forge)}
     mkl_random  {1.0.2 (anaconda) -> 1.0.4 (conda-forge)}
     numpy  {1.16.4 (anaconda) -> 1.16.4}
     numpy-base  {1.16.4 (anaconda) -> 1.16.4}
     openssl  {1.1.1 (anaconda) -> 1.1.1b (conda-forge)}
     scipy  {1.2.1 (anaconda) -> 1.3.0 (conda-forge)}
    +joblib-0.13.2 (conda-forge)
    +libblas-3.8.0 (conda-forge)
    +libcblas-3.8.0 (conda-forge)
    +liblapack-3.8.0 (conda-forge)
    +liblapacke-3.8.0 (conda-forge)
    +libopenblas-0.3.6
    +openblas-0.3.5 (conda-forge)
    +scikit-learn-0.21.2 (conda-forge)

2019-06-26 13:08:05  (rev 4)
     tk  {8.6.8 (anaconda) -> 8.6.9 (conda-forge)}
    +cycler-0.10.0 (conda-forge)
    +dbus-1.13.6 (conda-forge)
    +expat-2.2.5 (conda-forge)
    +fontconfig-2.13.1 (conda-forge)
    +freetype-2.10.0 (conda-forge)
    +gettext-0.19.8.1 (conda-forge)
    +glib-2.58.3 (conda-forge)
    +gst-plugins-base-1.14.5 (conda-forge)
    +gstreamer-1.14.5 (conda-forge)
    +icu-58.2 (conda-forge)
    +jpeg-9c (conda-forge)
    +kiwisolver-1.1.0 (conda-forge)
    +libiconv-1.15 (conda-forge)
    +libpng-1.6.37 (conda-forge)
    +libuuid-2.32.1 (conda-forge)
    +libxcb-1.13 (conda-forge)
    +libxml2-2.9.9 (conda-forge)
    +matplotlib-3.1.0 (conda-forge)
    +matplotlib-base-3.1.0 (conda-forge)
    +pcre-8.41 (conda-forge)
    +pthread-stubs-0.4 (conda-forge)
    +pyparsing-2.4.0 (conda-forge)
    +pyqt-5.9.2 (conda-forge)
    +python-dateutil-2.8.0 (conda-forge)
    +qt-5.9.7 (conda-forge)
    +sip-4.19.8 (conda-forge)
    +tornado-6.0.3 (conda-forge)
    +xorg-libxau-1.0.9 (conda-forge)
    +xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3 (conda-forge)

2019-06-26 13:10:31  (rev 5)
     ca-certificates  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.5.15 (anaconda)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.6.16 (anaconda)}
     openssl  {1.1.1b (conda-forge) -> 1.1.1 (anaconda)}
    +cloudpickle-1.1.1 (anaconda)
    +cytoolz-0.9.0.1 (anaconda)
    +dask-core-1.2.2 (anaconda)
    +imageio-2.5.0 (anaconda)
    +libtiff-4.0.10 (anaconda)
    +networkx-2.3 (anaconda)
    +olefile-0.46 (anaconda)
    +pillow-6.0.0 (anaconda)
    +pywavelets-1.0.3 (anaconda)
    +scikit-image-0.15.0 (anaconda)
    +toolz-0.9.0 (anaconda)
    +zstd-1.3.7 (anaconda)

2019-06-26 13:12:14  (rev 6)
     ca-certificates  {2019.5.15 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     openssl  {1.1.1 (anaconda) -> 1.1.1b (conda-forge)}
    +tensorflow-hub-0.5.0 (conda-forge)

2019-06-26 13:13:00  (rev 7)
     tensorboard  {1.13.1 (anaconda) -> 1.13.1 (conda-forge)}

2019-06-26 13:13:47  (rev 8)
     ca-certificates  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.5.15 (anaconda)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.6.16 (anaconda)}
     openssl  {1.1.1b (conda-forge) -> 1.1.1 (anaconda)}
    +pandas-0.24.2 (anaconda)
    +pytz-2019.1 (anaconda)

2019-06-26 13:14:36  (rev 9)
     ca-certificates  {2019.5.15 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     openssl  {1.1.1 (anaconda) -> 1.1.1b (conda-forge)}
    +pydicom-1.2.2 (conda-forge)

2019-06-26 13:19:06  (rev 10)
     ca-certificates  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.5.15 (anaconda)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (conda-forge) -> 2019.6.16 (anaconda)}
     openssl  {1.1.1b (conda-forge) -> 1.1.1 (anaconda)}
    +attrs-19.1.0 (anaconda)
    +bleach-3.1.0 (anaconda)
    +defusedxml-0.6.0 (anaconda)
    +entrypoints-0.3 (anaconda)
    +gmp-6.1.2 (anaconda)
    +ipykernel-5.1.1 (anaconda)
    +ipywidgets-7.4.2 (anaconda)
    +jinja2-2.10.1 (anaconda)
    +jsonschema-3.0.1 (anaconda)
    +jupyter-1.0.0 (anaconda)
    +jupyter_client-5.2.4 (anaconda)
    +jupyter_console-6.0.0 (anaconda)
    +jupyter_core-4.4.0 (anaconda)
    +libsodium-1.0.16 (anaconda)
    +markupsafe-1.1.1 (anaconda)
    +mistune-0.8.4 (anaconda)
    +nbconvert-5.5.0 (anaconda)
    +nbformat-4.4.0 (anaconda)
    +notebook-5.7.8 (anaconda)
    +pandoc-2.2.3.2 (anaconda)
    +pandocfilters-1.4.2 (anaconda)
    +prometheus_client-0.6.0 (anaconda)
    +pyrsistent-0.14.11 (anaconda)
    +pyzmq-18.0.0 (anaconda)
    +qtconsole-4.5.1 (anaconda)
    +send2trash-1.5.0 (anaconda)
    +terminado-0.8.2 (anaconda)
    +testpath-0.4.2 (anaconda)
    +webencodings-0.5.1 (anaconda)
    +widgetsnbextension-3.4.2 (anaconda)
    +zeromq-4.3.1 (anaconda)

2019-06-26 13:33:00  (rev 11)
     ca-certificates  {2019.5.15 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     certifi  {2019.6.16 (anaconda) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
     openssl  {1.1.1 (anaconda) -> 1.1.1b (conda-forge)}
    +binutils_impl_linux-64-2.31.1
    +binutils_linux-64-2.31.1
    +gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0 (conda-forge)
    +gcc_linux-64-7.3.0 (conda-forge)
    +gxx_impl_linux-64-7.3.0 (conda-forge)
    +gxx_linux-64-7.3.0 (conda-forge)
    +keras-2.2.4 (conda-forge)
    +libgpuarray-0.7.6 (conda-forge)
    +mako-1.0.10 (conda-forge)
    +pygpu-0.7.6 (conda-forge)
    +pyyaml-5.1.1 (conda-forge)
    +theano-1.0.4 (conda-forge)
    +yaml-0.1.7 (conda-forge)
```

Comment: It is possible that you have to check your revisions list and do a couple of installations. In my case the relation between tensorflow and cuda got damaged and I had to go two revisions before update event.

Comment: What am I supposed to see in "conda list --revisions"?  I don't have any package named conda there. I do see day by day reports that list (rev 1) through (rev 20).  Is that what you mean by "--revision" in CLI?

Comment: @pauljohn32 You should see a list of package changes by revision--like version updates. I see something like `conda  {4.6.14 -> 4.7.5}`. Hmm you don't see `conda` in there? Is the `conda` package manager working for you, like to install packages, etc.

Comment: @pauljohn32 First you have to activate the environment that has conflict or which you want to check for revisions. This is done through: ``conda activate name_of_environment``. then you write ``conda list --revisions`` and you should get  information in the shell about all installations and changes you have made to your conda environment

Answer (score 2):

```
conda update conda-build
```

Output:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:
conda-build                                 3.17.8-py37_0 --> 3.18.5-py37_0
```

The output of the `conda info` command (the conda-build has been updated from 3.17.8):

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/<user>/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/<user>/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.18.5
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /Users/<user>/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/<user>/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/<user>/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/<user>/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/18.5.0 OSX/10.14.4
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : /Users/<user>/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `conda update conda-build` worked for me too, and there is no need to first run `pip install conda-build` prior to running it.

Afterwards, the warning is gone.

Answer (score 1):

To me the solution was (in the Anaconda Prompt) running the following:

- `conda install anaconda`
- `conda update conda-build`
- `conda update --all`

After that the warning message disappear and I could update/install packages again.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux64 and after an installation yesterday I had the following problem: warning to update "conda-build" came along with "*Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3. Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions* ".
I followed the steps indicated by @msarahan in an issue in GitHub - go to: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8832.

**Steps:**

1 - install anaconda from https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
2 - update conda: conda update conda
3 - conda install hdf5 - "*see the warning*"
4 - conda update conda-build "(conda-build is part of anaconda since 2018.12, IIRC)"

5 - conda install hdf5 - "*warning is gone*"

It works for me. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following things:
Tried both remove and update`conda-build`, however, it didn't found the package

1. `Pip install conda-build`
2. It gave me an error, but I could do afterward
3. `Conda install conda-build`

Problem solved

Hope it helps